# How can I add a tab to the admin/content page

Tags: views, 8, routes

I'm new to drupal, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

While developing a module, is it possible to add a tab to the /admin/content page (where by default there is content, comments, files)

Currently using 8.0.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar to Drupal 7, tabs are called "local tasks". Your module should implement a local task and a route.

The complexity in this is that `/admin/content` is a views-generated route with a system module fallback in case the view is disabled (as explained by @Berdir below), and the base route should be `system.admin_content`.

```
mymodule.mytask:
  title: 'My Task'
  route_name: 'mymodule.mytask.route'
  base_route: 'system.admin_content'
  weight: 1
```

If the view itself isn't altered, then the route is `view.ID.page_NUMBER`. I've done this latter thing working on an entity example module in my sandbox (Shift).

Comment: Almost correct, /admin/content is a special case that's defined in system.routing.yml and then overridden, so that there's a fallback if views/node isn't enabled. The route name is system.admin_content, see comment.links.task.yml

Comment: I was so close... Had implemented the route and added it to system.admin_content. Just in the .links.menu.yml file not the task one.

Answer (score 5):

The tab "file" for example is configured in a view:

```
admin/structure/views/view/files:
PAGE SETTINGS
Path:/admin/content/files
Menu:Tab: Files
```

You can do the same with yml files in your module:

[Providing module-defined menu links](https://www.drupal.org/node/2122241)

[Routing system in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/routing)

An example from core module comment:

mymodule.links.task.yml:

```
comment.admin:
  title: Comments
  route_name: comment.admin
  base_route: system.admin_content
```

(credit: comment from Berdir)

Comment: Sorry. I saw your answer second so the tick went to mradcliffe. Good answer and thanks for the links too.